# PostgreSQL: Is it possible that using trigger delete can work as update

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I want to use trigger on specific table where task is to perform update on one column of each row when request for delete is made.

I cant use `INSTEAD OF` here as it only supports view.

Comment: [Rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrule.html)

Answer (score 3):

Two ways I can think of straight away:

1. Create a rule for such behaviour with [`CREATE RULE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrule.html)
2. Create a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger performing `UPDATE` when fired and return `NULL` from it. See [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html)